# NextJs rewrites does not proxy API calls in getServerSideProps

Tags: next.js, proxy, react-query, prefetch, nextjs-rewrites

I am using react-query `prefetchQuery` and NextJS (v.13) `getServerSideProps` along with its `rewrites` option in `next.config.js` file to proxy API calls.

The `rewrites` looks like this:

```
async rewrites() {
  return [
    {
      source: "/api/:slug*",
      destination: "http://test.example.com/api/:slug*",
    },
  ];
},
```

The problem is, this proxying does not work in `getServerSideProps`. The API response is 404 not Found.

Here is what I am doing in `getServerSideProps`:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

await Promise.all([queryClient.prefetchQuery(["getData"], async () => await getData())]);
```

where the EndPoint being called in `getData` is `/api/get_page_data`.
But everything works fine when I change the EndPoint to an absolute URL, like `http://test.example.com/api/get_page_data`.

P.S.: I am using Axios for calling APIs, in case this info is helpful.

Comment: I'm also interested on the solution. Did you find anything ?